# React Native Полупрозрачный TabBar

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

Я пытаюсь сделать фон tabBar полупрозрачный, но мне мешает внутрейний  темный border , как от него избавиться ?

```
<Tabs
  initialRouteName="home/index"
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarShowLabel: false,
    tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
    tabBarStyle: {
      position: 'absolute',
      height: 65,
      padding: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
    }
  }}>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]